# sql for the one entry in each group that meets a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query

```
SELECT ckt, setpt, clock FROM progs 
WHERE feed = "80302" AND day=4 AND clock<"12:15:00" 
ORDER BY ckt, clock DESC
```

That gets me this:

```
ckt setpt clock
0 69  06:06:00
0 62  00:30:00
1 57  10:30:00
1 67  04:30:00
1 57  01:30:00
2 69  11:00:00
2 62  00:30:00
```

How could I modify this query to give me the MAX(clock) for each CKT

In total:
Each `ckt`and `day` has a number of `setpt` and `clock` `entries`. I am looking for the (1 or none) `clock` record < some_time for each `ckt` and `day`. ie

```
0 69  06:06:00
1 67  10:30:00
2 69  11:00:00
```

in mysql.

Comment: Surely the desired results for `ckt` 1 should be `1 57  10:30:00`, not `1 67  10:30:00`? (The value of `setpt` at 10:30:00 for `ckt` 1 is 57, in the supplied sample data.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT ckt, MAX(setpt), MAX(clock)
FROM progs 
WHERE feed = "80302" AND day=4 AND clock<"12:15:00" 
GROUP BY ckt
ORDER BY ckt, clock DESC
```

**Result**

```
| CKT | MAX(SETPT) |                     MAX(CLOCK) |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   0 |         69 | January, 01 1970 06:06:00+0000 |
|   1 |         67 | January, 01 1970 10:30:00+0000 |
|   2 |         69 | January, 01 1970 11:00:00+0000 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01b4ee/3)

Comment: This will not work -- first ORDER BY should come after GROUP BY.  Second, using MAX(setpt) will not get the same result.

Comment: @sgeddes It does get the same result. Fixed the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: This query produces the desired results included in the question, but those data do not match the OP's requested methodology. Clarification from the OP is required.

Comment: My understanding of OPs question (although not desired results), OP wants MAX(clock) -- for row ckt=1, that would be 10:30, but setpt would be 57.

Comment: Yeah that is great. I wasn't clear. I had to remove MAX fro around `setpt` since I didn't want to scramble the setpts and times, needing only the setpt for the time (most) < 12:30

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to `JOIN` the table to itself, joining on the `MAX(clock)`:

```
SELECT p.ckt, p.setpt, p.clock 
FROM progs p
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(clock) maxClock, ckt
        FROM progs 
        WHERE feed = "80302" 
            AND day=4 
            AND clock<"12:15:00" 
        GROUP BY ckt
    ) p2 on p.ckt = p2.ckt AND p.clock = p2.maxclock
ORDER BY p.ckt, p.clock DESC
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01b4ee/9) (borrowed from other post)

Producing:

```
0   69  January, 01 1970 06:06:00+0000
1   57  January, 01 1970 10:30:00+0000
2   69  January, 01 1970 11:00:00+0000
```

Please note row with id 1 is different than your desired results, but match your question's desired results...

Comment: I wish I knew how to take a problem and construct joins to answer it. From your sql I can deconstruct that here the idea is to just find the max time < 12:30 and then add in the setpt by joining it to the results of the inner query. Thanks

Comment: @mcktimo -- be careful with the accepted solution -- it will just return an arbitrary value for setpt if you just removed the max from it since you're grouping by ckt.  Glad we could help!